# wp7 app version change

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to submit update for wp7 app. My current version is 1.0. I want to give 1.1 for the update. For submitting update should I change the version attribute of the WMAppManifest file manually or will it be updated automatically based on version no that we give in product form in the app hub.Also do we need to make any change in assemblyinfo.cs file in order to change the version no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't hurt to change both AssemblyInfo.cs and WMAppManifest.xml, but it's the value that you select during App submission/update that will be displayed to users.

Comment: If the "selected" value doesn't match WMAppManifest.xml, the AppHub provides you with a nice cozy error. (Or at least used to). Silly thing really, but Microsoft loves making people type in dublicated info.