# How to syncronize Manifest version with assembly version

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have read that "[Microsoft likes making people enter duplicate information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7634652/561759)", but I'm having trouble accepting that.

There is a Version in the app manifest, and a version in assemblyinfo.cs. I am using default build and revision numbers in the assemblyinfo file as follows:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.*")]
```

But I still seem to have to copy the build version into the manifest file WMAppManifest.xml manually.

```
 <App xmlns="" RuntimeType="Silverlight" Version="1.1.0.6" ...>
```

Outside of setting up a tt template and build action to regenerate the manifest after build, is there no easy way to synchronize these version numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in automatic way of updating these, but they are also not used by anything in the Store. Submission no longer reads the value in `WMAppManifest.xml`, so really the idea would be to choose the one you want to use in your internal code (for example, in your About page) and then you only need to remember to update that one.

In terms of common practice, I can only speak to what I have seen and that itself is divided in two. People with relatively simple applications / games use a hardcoded `const string` property somewhere in their app with a version string and don't touch any other file.

Others use Visual Studio to increment the versions in `assemblyinfo.cs` (by using `*`) and then read those out directly. I haven't seen anyone that religiously maintains and updates their `WMAppManifest.xml` version information.

By the way, the reason `WMAppManifest.xml` has a version string at all, is that that is what the Phone uses at install time, but the value itself is overridden by the Store when you submit your application, regardless of what value you put in there yourself.

Comment: Would good common practice to just be to leave the value blank (I believe it defaults to 1.0.0.0), and then just copy the assembly version to the store XAP submission on publish? I should have expanded my answer a bit maybe to ask what is the common practice.